# How to get data between two dates with timespan in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, windows, datetime

I want to export data into excel from database, but in Excel I want data with timespan of some minutes or hours.

So I am taking hours and minutes from two separate comboboxes and selecting datetime from two datetime pickers. And my data is minute by minute.So want data with 5 minutes time span?

data is like this:

[image]

I want data from 4:32:44 to 4:38:45 with 1 minutes gap means

```
4:32:44
4:33:44
4:34:44
```

So how can I do this:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`BETWEEN` keyword**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) to search for values between two values:

> The `BETWEEN` operator is used to select values within a range.

Here is an example snippet that might help:

```
Select ID, SomeColumn
from MyTable
Where SomeColumn between @Date1 and @Date2
```

Comment: No my data in database is per minute data like

Comment: Between will work with any data type that can be sorted

Comment: The code only answer has no value for future visitors. Adding an explanation would greatly help beginners.

Comment: @PeterMorris See Image in question??

Comment: Those look like dates to me, have you tried a parameterised query using DateTime parameters for Date1 and Date2 as per my example?

Comment: that query executes but i want data like 4:32:44
4:33:44
4:34:44 if you know is there is way to do this??

Comment: When you say "that query executes" do you mean that it brings back the correct rows but you need to know how to format the data in each row so it matches "hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew I can't think of any English explanation that shows what BETWEEN does, what kind of a clarification do you have in mind?